# How can I assign an external static IP to my machine?

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have recently moved ISP's and in this transition I acquired 4 static IP's. My plan was to move my 1U rack-mount server from the datacenter i use to my home as I do not need the redundancy, reliability or up-time outside of what i can offer at my house as it is mainly used for a remote workstation & for hosting game servers as and when I want to use them, and i figured i could do this 10 times cheaper at the expense of reliability.

Is it possible to use some level of consumer router to assign an external static IP to a machine behind the modem/router? or will I be able to forward all traffic from a specific external IP to a specific internal IP and what would the disadvantages be to this rather than having the machine sat directly on the external network?

Any guidance in this would be highly appreciated, this is probably my least knowledgeable area of IT.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will be using one-to-one NAT to achieve the publicIP > privateIP mapping. TP-Link and Linksys offer these settings on some consumer price-point routers (80-$120). Verify in the product documentation before purchase.

You'll usually find the setting under either 'Advanced > NAT > One-to-One NAT' or 'Setup > One-to-One NAT'. The documentation of your router should tell you exactly where to find it.

Typically the settings will look something like this:

Origin IP | Translated IP | WAN Interface | DMZ Disable | Active

TP Link Example (See models supported at top of page):

http://www.tp-link.com/lb/article/?faqid=381

If you're running a beefier Cisco router it get's a little more involved, but basically it's the same outside/inside mapping that occurs.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/13772-12.html?referring_site=bodynav